# Initializing arrays of type char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I want to initialize arbitrary large strings. It is null terminated string of characters, but I cannot print its content.
Can anybody tell me why?

```
char* b;
char c;
b = &c;
*b = 'm';
*(b+1) = 'o';
*(b+2) = 'j';
*(b+3) = 'a';
*(b+4) = '\0';
printf("%s\n", *b);
```

Comment: *(b+1) is a memory somewhere you don't own and shouldn't use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution invokes *undefined behaviour*, because `*(b+1)` etc. are outside the bounds of the stack variable `c`.  So when you write to them, you're writing all over memory that you don't own, which can cause all sorts of corruption.  Also, you need to `printf("%s\n", b)` (`printf` expects a pointer for `%s`).

The solution depends on what you want to do.  You can initialize a pointer to a string literal:

```
const char *str1 = "moja";
```

You can initialize a character array:

```
char str2[] = "moja";
```

This can also be written as:

```
char str2[] = { 'm', 'o', 'j', 'a', '\0' };
```

Or you can manually assign the values of your string:

```
char *str3 = malloc(5);
str3[0] = 'm';
str3[1] = 'o';
str3[2] = 'j';
str3[3] = 'a';
str3[4] = '\0';

...

free(str3);
```

Comment: and the printf requires a pointer with a %s, so it should be b, not *b. you could also explain him why taking the address of a single char and writing a string starting to that memory location is bad-bad-bad :)

Comment: almost there :) i'd upvote you but i don't agree completely with the overflow explanation.

Comment: @garph0: Which part do you disagree with?

Comment: The fact that overflowing c writes on memory you don't own. In the given example c is allocated on the stack, so you'll probably end overwriting other variables (or code) that you own. the effects, anyway, are usually corruption, I agree with that :-)

Answer (score 2):

This might result in a segmentation fault! *(b+1), *(b+2) etc refer to unallocated areas. First allocate memory and then write into it!

Comment: Also in your printf statement, just use 'b' instead of *b for printing a string

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign memory space for it, either with `malloc` or using a static array. Here, in your code, you're using the address of just one character to store at the addresses of that characters, **and** others following it. This is not defined.

Note, step by step, what you're doing. First, you assign the pointer to point to a single char space in memory. Then, by using `*b = 'm'` you set that memory to the character 'm'. But then, you access to the next memory position (that is undefined, because no memory is reserved for that position) to store another value. This won't work.

How to do it?

You have two options. For example:

```
char *b;
char c[5];
b = &c[0];
*b = 'm';
... //rest of your code
```

This will work because you have space for 5 chars in `c`. The other option is to directly assign memory for `b` using `malloc`:

```
char * b = (char*) malloc(5);
*b = 'm';
... // rest of your code
```

Finally, maybe not what you want, but you can either initialize a char array or pointer using a string literal:

```
char c[] = "hello";
const char* b = "abcdef";
```

Comment: nice explanation, but it's not true that it's undefined: it will just overwrite something else on the stack, since c is allocated on the stack. moreover, the problem with the printf is a different one :)

Answer (score 1):

`b` doesn't have enough space to hold all those characters. Allocate enough space using `malloc` or declare `b` as a `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the following instead of your printf, it will print the first character.

```
printf("%c\n", *b);
```

In order for you to have arbitrarily large strings, you will need to use a library such as [**bstring**](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/) or write one of your own.

This is because, in C one needs to get memory, use it and free it accordingly. `b` in your case only points to a character unless you allocate memory to it using `malloc`. And for `malloc` you have to specify a fixed size.

For arbitrarily large string, you need to encapsulate the actual pointer to character in a data structure of your own, and then manage its size according to the length of the string that is to be set as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not safe at all! You allocate only 1 char on the stack with `char c;` but write 5 chars into it! this will give you a stack-overflow which can be very dangerous.

Another thing: you mustn't dereference the string when printing it: `printf("%s\n", b);`

Why not simply write `const char *b = "mojo";`?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s\n", *b);
```

why *?

```
printf("%s\n", b);
```

is what you want

Answer (score 1):

The printf does not print because it expect a char*, so you should pass b, not *b.
To initialize a pointer to a string constant you can do something like:

`char *s1 = "A string"`

or

`char s2[] = "Another string"`

or allocate a buffer with `char *b = malloc(5)` and then write to this buffer (as you did, or with the string functions)

what you did was taking the address of a single char memory location and then write past to it, possibly overwriting other variables or instructions and thus possibly leading to data corruption or crash.